# Infinite arctan series

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I know that usually these types of problems deal with pattern recognition. There would be specific pattern as one proceeds from one term to another. But, in this problem I'm unable to recognize one. So, please give me some hints on starting the solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\arctan A+\arctan B$?

Comment: Yeah I know that......

Comment: Then use it to find the sum of the first 2 terms; then, the sum of the first 3 terms; then, look for a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\arctan{A}-\arctan{B} = \arctan{\frac{A - B}{1+A B}}$$

What if $A=2^{k+1}$ and $B=2^k$?...

Answer (score 2):

Hint regarding the pattern of terms:

$ x_0 = \frac13 = \frac{2^0}{2^{2\cdot 0+1}+1} $

$ x_1 = \frac29 = \frac{2^1}{2^{2\cdot 1+1}+1} $

$ x_2 = \frac4{33} = \frac{2^2}{2^{2\cdot 2+1}+1} $

...

$ x_k =  \frac{2^k}{2^{2k+1}+1} $